# Remove alternatively couple of items from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, range

This is my simplified NSMutableArray from a JSON parsing:

```
{
main 
{ 
  array0, 
  array1,
  array2,
  array3,    <----- remove!
  array4,    <----- remove!
  array5,
  array6,    <----- remove!
  array7,    <----- remove!
  array8,
  ...,
}
}
```

Im looking the best way to REMOVE SINGLE array items ALTERNATIVELY, example only arrays 2,4,6,8; **Also, if I need to remove COUPLES of array 3,4 and 6,7, always alternatively?**

EDIT: this is the first solution, to remove SINGLE items alternatively:

```
for (int i=0; i < [array count]; i = i+1) {
[array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Comment: use - (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index  and jenerate index as u want

Comment: Oh yes CRDave, I've edited my question, but if I need to remove ONLY a couple of arrays, ALTERNATIVELY?

Comment: It depend on your logic if u want 1 to 5 and you know pos statically than you can write 1 5 statement without loop. if you have patent than you can make loop which run only M number of time where M is number of item to remove so no extra run. but if u dont have any patent and you are removing randomly (without any math rules) than your loop hase to run N number of time where  N is array count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds like you could easily create an index set of all the indexes to remove and remove the objects at those indexes using `removeObjectsAtIndexes:`.

You can get the indexes of all the even (or odd) indexed objects from `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`.

```
NSMutableArray *array = // Your array where objects should be removed from
NSIndexSet *indexesToRemove = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return idx%2==0; // index is even (even objects get removed)
}];
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToRemove];
```

Comment: Thanks David, but XCode give error: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableIndexSet *__strong' with an expression of type 'NSIndexSet *', we need NSIndexSet :)

Comment: Sorry, it should be a normal NSIndexSet. That is what happens when you don't run your code. That should only be a warning though.

Comment: Sure, I've edited, but we have the problem to remove single COUPLE of arrays, alternatively, what's the best code to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `idx%4<2`? That should be true for 0 and 1 but false for 2 and 3. And then true for 4 and 5 again and so on.